# iPhone: Anchor UINavigationBar to bottom of screen

Tags: iphone, uitableview, view, uinavigationbar

I am creating a UINavigationBar which works fine.  But, it scrolls with my UITableView, which I don't want.  How can I anchor the navbar at the bottom of the screen, so that it does NOT scroll?

```
    bottomNav = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, 44.0)];
    bottomNav.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    [self.view addSubview:bottomNav];
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes, TechZen you were right.  I needed to add it to my parent view controller:

```
bottomNav = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, self.view.frame.size.height - 20, self.view.frame.size.width, 44.0)];
bottomNav.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
[self.parentViewController.view addSubview:bottomNav];
```

Comment: I will, but it says I can't for 2 days.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like your adding it to the tableview instead of view that contains the tableview. If `self` is a tableview controller that is definitely your problem.